# Makefile does not process all files in list

Tags: c++, makefile

This probably is something very basic, but I´m starting now with GNU Makefiles.

The way I did it is causing me 2 problems:

a) The way I build it is processing only the first file (`file1`).... The other files are not being processed (`file1`, `file2`, `file3`).

b) How can I add the `INCLUDES` as a dependence, like if a include file change to recompile the files.

**`Makefile:`**

```
IDIR = include
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj

CPPFLAGS=-I$(IDIR) -std=c++0x

CC = g++

INCLUDES = $(shell cat $(IDIR)/includes.mk )

PROGS = myprog

OBJS = file1 file2 file3 file4 file5

$(OBJS): 
    $(CC) $(SRCDIR)/$@.cpp -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$@.o $(CPPFLAGS)  


$(PROGS): $(OBJS)
     $(CC)  -o $@ $(CPPFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$(OBJS)    

all: $(PROGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you don't specify a target when you are running make, it only builds the first one.  Typically, the "all" target is at the top.

Comment: Uh... really works with `all` and solve my first problem. Is there a way to make `all` implicit on makefile?

Comment: Make sure `all` is your first target in your Makefile.

Comment: That problem is solved - thanks.... Now I´m having problems with `PROGS`, as they are in a directory.... How can I access them ? (see edited code)

Comment: There are some odd things about your makefile, like that the value of OBJS is not a list of .o files, but I'm not really understanding your issue.  What do you mean when you say you are having problems with PROGS?  What kind of access problem?  Giving explicit examples of what you are doing and what you are seeing and what you are expecting would be helpful.

Comment: Vaughn, I got your point and fixed the makefile... Now it´s working fine... Thanks.

Comment: There are so many mistakes in this makefile, you may like to start with a working example and modify it to suit your project.

Comment: Maxim, that´s what I did... Started over with Vaughn comments and now it is working fine... Thanks.

Comment: @Mendez: If you have a solution, please answer your own question and accept it. Alternatively, if you feel that there's not much value to future readers in doing so, consider deleting the question.